# How to multiple join tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

workers and experience

In table workers there is row worker_parent (because one worker can be responsible for other).

No I must connect tables like that:

```
SELECT w1.* FROM workers w1 LEFT JOIN workers w2 ON (w2.id = w1.worker_parent)
```

And that's ok. But I have to order by experience of w2 and I try to add table experience but it's connect to w1 and not to w2.

My question is how to add table experience (which has row worker_id) to w2 and order by experience AND SELECT data from w1.

This is my try.

```
SELECT w1.* FROM workers w1 LEFT JOIN workers w2 ON (w2.id = w1.worker_parent) LEFT JOIN experience e ON (w2.id = e.worker_id) ORDER BY e.experience DESC
```

Thank's for help

Comment: and whats wrong whit your query? its sort workers by there parents exprience, if they have a parent

Comment: Your SQL seems to be pretty correct although you are not showing any data from `W2` and `experience` tables. This means, if there are multiple rows for `W1` in `W2` and similarly for `W2` in `experience` you will multiple rows for each row in `W1` in your output. To understand you need to display some columns from `W2` and `Experience` in addition to your `W1` columns.

Comment: @somnath - I need data only from w1.

Comment: @CroiOS then you should be fine but as I said you will seeing multiple rows if the joined tables have multiple matching rows for each row in their parent table in the join.

Comment: @somnath - But I'm not getting experience, I know because when I select result is NULL (not 0 but null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want child workers that have a parent with experince,
you need to add a where (or change join type)
(for readability i renamed w1 and w2 to w_child and w_parent)

```
SELECT w_child.*, e_parent.experience
FROM workers AS w_child 
LEFT JOIN workers AS w_parent ON (w_parent.id = w_child.worker_parent) 
LEFT JOIN experience AS e_parent ON (w_parent.id = e_parent.worker_id) 
WHERE e_parent.worker_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e_parent.experience DESC
```